# Where can I find Take off and Landing Zones for GIS Integration?

Tags: flight-path, uk

I am a GIS specialist and looking to plot the take off and landing zones into major and minor airports across the UK. This is dominantly to see land affected by noise pollution from air traffic. If data exists for private airfields as well that will be a bonus.

High altitude flight paths data such as [this website](https://flightplandatabase.com/search?q=leeds&sort=updated&page=1) is not necessary as I simply require the bearing of take off and landing zones into airports to an altitude of ~3280 ft. The referenced website download file formats are not exactly GIS friendly and the option to batch download multiple files does not exist.

File formats I'm looking for are either shapefile, gpkg, kml (google earth) or GeoJSON and a batch download for all landing and take off zones will be desirable.

Comment: are you looking for IFR, VFR or both?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you might try [opendata.se].

Comment: You mean runways?